# Passing Map data from servlet to jsp select tag

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

i cant see whats wrong with the following code, it doesnt pass any data from Map to jsp select tag options.

Heres my model class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq", sequenceName = "seq1", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_seq")
public int id;
public String customerType;

@ElementCollection
@Column(name = "customerType")
public Map<String, String> customerTypes;


public Customer() {}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


  public void setCustomerTypes(Map<String, String> customerTypes) {

  this.customerTypes = customerTypes;

  }

  public Map<String, String> getCustomerTypes() {

      return customerTypes;
   }


public String getCustomerType() {
    return customerType;
}


public void setCustomerType(String customerType) {



    this.customerType = customerType;
}


}
```

Servlet, here i add the select options in the map and pass them to jsp page

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    showForm(request, response);

}
private void showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

       map.put("", " ");
       map.put("customerType.private", "Private");
       map.put("customerType.corporate", "Corporate");

    Customer customer = new Customer();

    customer.setCustomerTypes(map);
    request.setAttribute("customerType", customer);

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/Add.jsp").forward(request, response);    
}
```

And the jsp part :

```
  <select id="customerTypeSelect" name="customerType" >

   <c:forEach var="entry" items="${customer.customerTypes}">

    <c:set var="selected" value="" scope="request"/>

      <c:if test="${entry.key == customer.customerType}">
      <c:set var="selected" value="selected=\"selected\"" scope="request"/>
    </c:if>
    <option value="${entry.key}" ${selected}>${entry.value}</option>
  </c:forEach>

 </select>
```

Comment: Here `items="${customer.customerTypes}"` (in `<c:forEach>`), what is `customer.customerTypes`?

Comment: Its supposed to be reference to the map in the model class

Comment: Absolutely, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing code as below,

you are setting `customer` object as below,

```
 request.setAttribute("customerType", customer);
```

key here is `customerType`, and you have used `customer`,

1.) so either user `customerType` as key in jsp as below

```
<select id="customerTypeSelect" name="customerType" >

   <c:forEach var="entry" items="${customerType.customerTypes}">

    <c:set var="selected" value="" scope="request"/>

      <c:if test="${entry.key == customerType.customerType}">
      <c:set var="selected" value="selected=\"selected\"" scope="request"/>
    </c:if>
    <option value="${entry.key}" ${selected}>${entry.value}</option>
  </c:forEach>

 </select>
```

or

2.) do below in your servlet

```
request.setAttribute("customer", customer);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for this silly mistake for an hour while you found it in few minutes. Again, thanks.

Comment: I will not ankhur-singhal.